# Redirect with a Response in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Is there a way to redirect with a response in a Spring MVC Controller? Using ModelAndView with ResponseBody only redirects with an empty body.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView redirectWithResponse(@RequestParam("redirect_url") String redirectUrl,
                                         @RequestParam("data") String data) {

    MyJSONResponse response = new MyJSONResponse(data);

    ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("redirect:"+redirectUrl);
    modelAndView.addObject(response);
    return modelAndView;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to copy them over to `RedirectAttributes`:

```
public ModelAndView redirectWithResponse(@RequestParam("redirect_url")
  String redirectUrl, @RequestParam("data") String data,
  RedirectAttributes redir) {
    ...

    MyJSONResponse response = new MyJSONResponse(data);

    ModelAndView modelAndView = 
            new ModelAndView("redirect:" + redirectUrl);
    redir.addFlashAttribute("object", response);
    return modelAndView;
    ...
}
```

the scope of the flash attributes is request, they'll survive the redirect, but will be removed after being used